# Issuer certificate is invalid in self signed SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have created a SSl certificate using these commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out kc_ca-key 2048
openssl req -new -out san_domain.csr -key kc_ca-key -config openssl.cnf
openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in san_domain.csr -signkey kc_ca-key -out kc_ca-cert -extensions v3_req -extfile openssl.cnf
```

openssl.cnf file contains the common name, country name, subject alternative name and all such information.
In browser, I am able to connect securely after importing this certificate but when i run curl command with same certificate, i get the following error:

NSS error -8156 (SEC_ERROR_CA_CERT_INVALID)
* Issuer certificate is invalid.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (60) Issuer certificate is invalid.
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).

How to resolve this error

Comment: was there a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information to determine what your problem is.

I am making the following assumptions:

1. You sent the certificate request (CSR) to a CA provider and got a certificate back.
2. You setup some sort of web server with that certificate
3. I am also assuming that you used a "Windows" web browser like IE or Chrome that uses the windows certificate store to test the certificate.
4. The CA that signed your certificate is a well known CA that has there root certificates in all the common CA Lists.

If the above is true and a web browser like Firefox (that uses it's internal CA list) fails it's because the web server is using a certificate without any intermediate certificates.

You need to go find the intermediate certificates for your CA signed certificate, combine them into a certificate chain and setup your web server with this certificate chain.  The details of how to do this will depend on your web server.

Once the web server is setup with a correct certificate chain then your curl command (and firefox) should work fine.

The reason that windows works fine is because windows keeps a list of common intermediate certificates that it can verify a certificate chain with.  A openssl based client doesn't, so the intermediate certificates have to come from the SSL socket server (e.g. web server) down to the client to be able to verify the certificate chain back to a trusted root certificate in the client CA list.